# javascript - replace double quotes in a string to parse string to JSON

Tags: javascript, string, replace, double-quotes

I want to replace double quotes inside a quote by javascript and convert it to JSON.

This is my code.

```
var str = '{"data" : "name \"example\""}';
// if I keep this string and parse to JSON
str = JSON.parse(str);
// I get this error "Unexpected token in JSON"
// now I want to replace '\"' into '\\\"' then I can parse it to JSON
var newStr = '{"data" : "name \\\"example\\\""}';
newStr = JSON.parse(newStr);
```

My expected result is '{"data" : "\\"example\\""}'.

I tried some ways but I have not found any correct way. I need a help.

Comment: why are you attempting to do this? The value of your `str` variable is different from what you think it is. `\"` within a string produces a value of `"`, which means your `str` value contains double double quotes. `""example""` and exactly 0 backslash characters. Having seen quite a number of similar questions in the past, I can only assume that you're significantly misunderstanding a variety of encodings. In this case JSON, and string encodings in particular.

Comment: I want to parse this String to json but I always got this error "Unexpected token in JSON". I have read some posts and the problem is solved if I can replace \" to \\\".
I already edited my post please have a look

Comment: It's impossible. the exact str is  {"data" : "name "example""}.  there is not any "\" character in your str.

Answer (score 0):

The value for `str` is actually:

```
"{"data" : ""example""}"
```

Therefore, to achieve the output you want you can use the following:

```
str.replace(/""/g, '"-');
```

Run this snippet to see this in action

```js
var str = '{"data" : "\"example\""}';

console.log("str before replace: " + str);

console.log(str.replace(/""/g, '"-'));

var strNew = '{"data" : "name \"example\""}';
```

Comment: So just to be clear: you are asking to do a replace on the double quotes surrounding `example` in the following string: `"{"data" : "name "example""}"`?  Any chance of an up-vote for the original answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace(/(""(.*?)"")/g, '"-$2-"')` Working snippet is below:

```js
var str = '{"data" : "\"example\""}';
// str is now:
// {"data" : ""example""}
console.log(str);

//we want double quote to become "- or -"
// first find out the string between
var regexp = /(""(.*?)"")/g
// replace it with "- and -"
// note that $1 is now ""example"" and $2 is example (without double quote)
var modifiedStr = str.replace(regexp, '"-$2-"');
console.log(modifiedStr);
```

The editted question is just impossible.

Prove: 
Think of `{"sth": "a quote of code: ", "another thing": "test", "exclamation mark": "!"}`, it can be

```
{
  "sth": "a quote of code: ",
  "another thing": "test",
  "exclamation mark": "!"
}
```

or,

```
{
  "sth": "a quote of code: \", \"another thing\": \"test\", \"exclamation mark\": \"!"
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var sth = 'a quote of code: ", "another thing": "test", "exclamation mark": "!';
var sth2 = sth.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
var str  = '{"sth": "' + sth  + '"}';
var str2 = '{"sth": "' + sth2 + '"}';
console.log("sth:  " + sth);
console.log("sth2: " + sth2);
console.log("str: " + str);
console.log("str2: " + str2);
console.log("would you parse it to:");
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
console.log("or");
console.log(JSON.parse(str2));
```

Comment: @user3079975 you should not use JSON like this, if you have a string, you can just make a real object and store it, then `JSON.stringify` it back.

Comment: @user3079975 It is impossible to do that, think of a situation, the string is now `{"sth": "a quote of code: ", "another thing": "test", "exclamation mark": ""!"}`, would you parse it to `{"sth": "a quote of code: \", \"another thing\": \"test\", \"exclamation mark\": \"\"!"}` or `{"sth": "a quote of code: ", "another thing": "test", "exclamation mark": "\"!"}`? It's impossible to code in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is replace the double quotes in any string value of a JSON, and the JSON string should be parse to an object.

The 100% safe way to do this is parse it to object, traverse all key value pairs and replace all string type value, then stringify it to a string.

```
// this for generate your target str.
let originObj = {data:"this is a \"example\"", id:1234, type:"string"} 
// this str is your target str.
let str = JSON.stringify(originObj); 
// "{"data":"this is a \"example\"","id":1234,"type":"string"}"
let obj = JSON.parse(str);  // parse it to obj
for (let k in obj) {
     if (typeof obj[k] === 'string'){
          obj[k] = obj[k].replace('"', '-');
     }
}
str = JSON.stringify(obj);
// "{"data":"this is a -example-","id":1234,"type":"string"}"
```